# nHibernate -> Dependency in the UI layer

Tags: c#, nhibernate, reference, dependencies

We want to take advantage of nHibernate's "Unit of Work" functionality. To accomplish this in our C# WinForms app, we need to open a session from within the UI layer i.e when a form opens. Perform some work and then close the session when we close the form.

This form based approach seems very logical except for the fact that we now require a reference to nHibernate from our UI layer! Where should we be referencing nHibernate, I would have thought we can accomplish thish without having to reference it from within our UI layer?

Comment: Why is that not logical? The unit of work boundary is determined by the UI, so for me it sounds very logical.

Comment: Paco, it is logical to have the UI as boundary for UoW, but having a reference to a concrete persistance library in the UI layer is a code stink.  The UI shouldn't know anything about a specific implementation, it should only about the concept of a UoW.  Ryudice has basically answered Josata's question.

Comment: If you  create a wrapper around it, the UI also knows about the implementation, it knows around the wrapper, and to prevent that, you need a wrapper around a wrapper, etc. You make some statements without giving any reason for it.

Comment: why the down vote? Seems an appropriate question, who want a direct reference to the ORM in the UI layer. Jeez you're a sensitive bunch!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a session manager class, which would be a wrapper for binding the nhibernate session. Something like this:

```
    public class SessionManager : ISessionManager
{
    private  readonly ISessionFactory _sessionFactory;

     SessionManager()
    {
        _sessionFactory = CreateSessionFactory();
    }

    public void OpenSession()
    {
        ISession session = _sessionFactory.OpenSession();

        session.BeginTransaction();

        CurrentSessionContext.Bind(session);
    }


    public void CloseSession()
    {
        ISession session = CurrentSessionContext.Unbind(_sessionFactory);


        if (session == null) return;


        try
        {
            session.Transaction.Commit();
        }

        catch (Exception)
        {
            session.Transaction.Rollback();
        }

        finally
        {
            session.Close();

            session.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Just create the CreateSessionFactory method.

Comment: ..and ISessionManager would live next to abstract repositories (IRepository) whilst SessionManager would live with the NHibernate repository implementation.  Not in the UI layer (or project).